# How do I close web3 such that mocha tests exit properly?

Tags: web3js, nodejs, testing, mocha

I'm writing a simple NodeJS (Node 9.4.0) server that's using `web3 (1 beta)` to interact with Ethereum.

I've created a simple utility `web3` as follows:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const url = process.env.WEB3_PROVIDER_URL || 'ws://localhost:8546'
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || url)

module.exports = web3
```

I've written a trivial `mocha` (4.0) test as follows

```
const { expect } = require('chai')
const web3 = require('../../../src/utils/web3')

describe('web3', () => {
  it('exists', () => {
    expect(web3).to.exist
  })
})
```

The test passes fine but mocha never exists unless I add the `--exit` flag.

How can I close or otherwise cleanup `web3` after my test so mocha exists correctly without the use of the `--exit` flag?

Comment: I believe you have to use the done() function to finish the "it" test, no?

Comment: that's only for asynchronous tests

Answer (score -1):

Does it work like this?

```
describe('web3', () => {
  it('exists', (done) => {
    if(web3.currentProvider) {
      web3.currentProvider.reset() // or something...
    }
    done();
  })
})
```

The code above is untested, but you may get the idea.